# using WL.TabBar in Server_Generated_Pages renders items as list items instead of tabs

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use WL.TabBar api and create tabs in the server generated pages but looks like items are not rendered as tabs. But rendered one below the other with dots for each items (like indicated/shown below).

*Item1
*Item2
*Item3
*Item4

Any idea what could be the problem ?. Thanks

Cool, Here are the environment details:

(1) Worklight version 506. Running on Android simulator

(2) Sample code used:

> WL.TabBar.setParentDivId("tabpane");
>   WL.TabBar.init();
>   WL.TabBar.addItem("item1", function()
>   { openNativePage(); },"Item1",{  image: "css/images/Tab.jpg",
>   imageSelected : "css/images/Tab.jpg"
>   ? });
>   WL.TabBar.setVisible(true);

(3) I don't see any error messages as such. But I see the below warning in LogCat:

> 05-16 12:37:42.796: I/Web Console(289): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. at hostname/wps/contenthandler/!ut/p/digest!SlQs_clcwL2z1b8kIsNvEg/mashup/ra:collection?themeID=ZJ_CGAH47L00OEP00IDBHRNLP0830&locale=en&mime-type=text%2Fplain&entry=wl_client__0.0%3Aconfig_js&entry=wl_init__0.0%3Aconfig_js&entry=wp_theme_high_contrast__0.0%3Aconfig_js&entry=wp_theme_edit__0.0%3Aconfig_js&entry=wp_theme_menus__0.0%3Aconfig_js&entry=wp_theme_skin_region__0.0%3Aconfig_js&entry=wp_one_ui_30__0.0%3Aconfig_js&entry=wp_status_bar__0.0%3Aconfig_js:1044

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hmm, I think found the answer. The problem was the CSS files (wlclient.css + wlgap.android.css) were missing at backed the Server (where the custom application exist). I had copied only the native JavaScript files from wlclient and commons folder. Thanks.

Comment: If this has indeed solved your issue, please mark this question as Answered when you are able to. Thanks.

Comment: I can't accept my own answers :-). Probably you could and plus some +ve vote :-). I think may be we can add in specific somewhere in the documentation (server generated pages) that the client libraries include the css + images + javascript so will have to copy the whole stuff. Thanks

Comment: I can't accept an answer, only the person who asked it, can. Once you have enough reputation points you will be able to. Thanks.

Comment: oh ok I didn't know this (my be I should have searched). Thanks.